# [UWP]Toggle visibility of a Datagrid Row using VisualState.StateTriggers

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, datagrid, uwp-xaml

I am using a DataGrid in UWP to display a table. I wish to toggle the visibility of the rows based on the value of a property in the itemsource using VisualState.StateTriggers.

```
        <Style x:Key="RowStyle" TargetType="controls:DataGridRow">
             <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding Delete, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityToBoolConverter}}" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                </VisualState>
               </VisualStateGroup>
           </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Style>


 <controls:DataGrid
                        x:Name="grid"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyle}"
                        Height="auto">
 </controls:DataGrid>
```

ItemSource is an ObvervableCollection of

```
public class StudentsList {
                  public int Id;
                  public string Name;
                  public bool IsDeleted;
}
```

I wish to collapse or disable all the rows where IsDeleted is true , using VisualState.StateTriggers only.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems difficult to operate on a certain row with DataGrid, because DataGrid is actually a collection of many listviews. You can ask for help here 
https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do this in another way like in the code-behind which will be more easy.

1. Find any column in the DataGrid
2. Find the element in the column which for the target Row
3. Find the target Row by the element you found in Step3
4. Change the Visibility.

Here is the simple code:

```
       // get any column 
       DataGridColumn d =dataGrid1.Columns.ElementAt(0);
        //get the element which contains the item for the row
       TextBlock element =  d.GetCellContent(MyViewModel.Customers[0]) as TextBlock;
        // get target row
        DataGridRow ROW = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(element);
        // change visibility
        ROW.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```